# CRLF Injection into Web Page

Tags: xss, injection

I was pen-testing a site recently which I found a few issues in, and this continues to a previous question I asked about Null-byte string termination in web applications.

I have noticed that the site does not filter out URL Encoded CR/LF characters, and if I inject these characters, they do get respected in the source code (you can see the code gets shifted down in the page).

I have checked the returning headers, but there is no sign of any data which I try to inject, also any XSS characters I do inject get filtered (html entities) by the page ('<' => `&lt;`, etc)

So my question is, is this CRLF injection potentially exploitable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `CRLF` output shows in response header, it's vulnerable and exploitable (even if `< > "` chars is filterd) .

An attacker can use to `set-cookie` header for session-fixation attacks, or using to `location` and `cache` in headers and ... .

---

**update**

If your output is in html body it's not exploitable,CR LF Characters in HTML are white spaces .
But if it's in javascript it could be explitable .

Comment: Sure, I understand how CRLF injection usually works, but as this is not being injected into the headers, it's a strange one.

Comment: it's not exploitable,CR LF Characters in HTML body are white spaces .
But if output is in javascript it's exploitable .